# How to configure the environment for AMS-tex?

Tags: environments, compiling, amstex

I installed the Miktex, Winedt, and Texmaker in my PC.
And I saw that there is amstex in MikTex package manager. Unfortunately, I still can not successfully compile the files written in ams-tex, such as the the ams-guid.tex provided by [this wedsite](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amstex)
Here is my error message:[image: error messsage]
The reason that I use ams-tex is that my uncle's work are all write with ams-tex. Thus, he would like to keep using ams-tex rather than latex. However, I found that configuring the environment is not an easy work. Does anyone know how to build the environment properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build an *amstex format* (`amstex.fmt`), which is not done bt default. For that, launch `MiKTeX Settings`, right click on `amstex`, select `include` (so that at each update of amstex, the format will be redone then  right-click on `Build format`, like in this image:

[image]

You'll also have to configure TeXmaker so that you can launch amstex from within the interface.

*Edit*: If you have WinEdt installed, there is a menu item for AmSTeX in  `TeX > DVI >AmSTeX` (shortcut `Shift + Ctrl + A`).

Comment: Thank for your detailed reply despite that building an amstex format is unnecessary. This figure helps me to find out that my miktex is not in correct version.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to run `pdftex` (or `tex`) on a file with the following structure:

```
\input amstex.tex
\documentstyle{amsppt}

<the document>
```

just like the `amsguide.tex` file starts. The important thing is not to run `latex` in one of its flavors.

You can also build the format, but it's not required and does not really save time. On my machine the saving is less than 0.4 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It's correct and helpful.