# Need help adding AMSTeX fonts to compile a 35-year old document

Tags: fonts, miktex, missing, amstex

I have a 100-page document (my Ph.D. dissertation) that I created in the 1984-1985 time frame that I need to create a PDF from. I have not used TeX since about 1990 so my TeX knowledge is extremely rusty.

I installed MikTeX 2.9 on Win10 Pro 1909. I installed it for myself only as installing it for everyone fails at the very end, and the recommendation was to install it for a single user to get around that problem.

I need the AMSTeX fonts, as my 35 year old document uses those fonts (lots and lots of equations). From the MikTeX console, I was able to install the amstex package. But I am still unable to compile my document.

According to the instructions in this thread ([How to configure the environment for AMS-tex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475527/how-to-configure-the-environment-for-ams-tex/524886#524886)), I need to build an amstex format (not done by default). The instructions say to right-click on amstex in the Settings --> Formats tab, and select include. But even the screenshot provided shows no "Include". If I select Format properties, I get a pop-up for Format Definition, where there is a check box for "Exclude this format when updating all format files." The box is currently checked. If I uncheck the box and click Ok, I get an error that says "Built-in format definitions may not be changed."

So what I am supposed to do to include it? Running the console in Admin mode does not help since this is a single user installation (and the console shows nothing in admin mode).

I am able to "Build format" for amstex. But it only takes a second or two so I am not convinced anything got done, probably because amstex is excluded.

And I still cannot compile my document as it's looking for fonts that are not there.

Any help would be much appreciated. Please be specific since, as I mentioned above, my TeX knowledge is 30 years old.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the second answer in the linked Q&A? That does not require a format to be build and might be preferable in your case.

Comment: note the ams fonts are part of standard tex distribution, the amstex _macros_ are something else entirely did you write your thesis using amstex rather than latex?

Comment: you don't need to build an amstex format, if you are using amstex just use plain tex and put \input amstex at the top. Building a format would have saved you several minutes per run in 1995, now it  is unlikely to save you a second.

Comment: I suggest you cut down your document to just a couple of paragraphs (you can change all the words if needed, so long as it demonstrates the errors) then post it in a text block in your question along with the log file you get, then we can debug and tell you how to process the document on a current tex system.

Comment: What fonts are claimed to be missing? I bet they're `msxm` and `msym`.

Comment: @egreg and am fonts?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think am fonts were still distributed when AMS-TeX was released.

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult for you to look in my profile page and find a working email address to send me the material, which I hereby authorize you to do.

Comment: Thank you all for responding to my query for help so quickly and suggesting fixes. Let me try to respond to your comments with additional information per your requests.

Comment: @Ralf Stubner
I have added the following two lines
   \input amstex
   \documentstyle{amsppt}
to my include file. Running TeX again against just a subset of the document, TeX stopped immediately on "\input amstex" as it couldn't find it. So I copied the file to my document directory and tried again. It was then amsppt that could not be found.

So I deleted the copied amstex.tex file and ran TeX with the following command line argument:

tex --include-directory="C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\amstex\base" PR.TEX

Comment: @Ralf Stubner  TeX still could not find it amstex.tex. The file IS in that directory!!!! How am I supposed to specify input directories then?

So I recopied amstex.tex to my document directory and reran TeX. It included amtex.tex but then stopped on
\documentstyle{amsppt}

At this stage of the game, I figured I can't possibly have to copy every file it needs to my document directory, so I am obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: @David Carlisle
I wrote my thesis using Plain TeX (and the AMS fonts), after reading the TeX book back then in 1984 to learn how to use TeX. No I did not use LaTeX.
As I said above, adding \input amstex did not help (even with the file in my document directory) as the fonts are still missing.

Comment: @David Carlisle
I am running a subset of my document (4-5 pages). I copied amstex.tex, amsppt.sty and amsppt.sti to my document directory and reran TeX. Now it doesn't complain about not finding the amstex files, but still complains about not finding the fonts. The missing fonts file (missfont.log) and the TeX log of the subset of my document (PR.log), is available at this Google Drive folder: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U08cA0m_97e87kpWIZLM03N36dh9BG0p?usp=sharing
Let me know if you need to see other files.

Comment: @egreg
No, the missing fonts are not msxm nor msym (never heard of those fonts). The missing fonts are listed in the missfont.log mentioned above. There are 88 instances of them so I didn't want to put the entire list here. But the names all start with "am". I searched the entire MiKTeK installation tree structure for ambi*. Nothing. Nothing either for amr*, or any other fonts mentioned in the missfont.log file. So I wouldn't be able to run mktextfm on my list of missing fonts even if I wanted to. I don't even know what file extension it would look for.

Comment: Oh you made my day. My guess was right (missing am fonts) and @egreg's was wrong:-)

Comment: but where on earth did you find a copy of amstex.tex still using am fonts (which were replaced by computer modern in the 1980s) the amstex.tex in miktex or texlive does not use them  `texmf-dist/tex/amstex/base/amstex.tex`

Comment: you should not have to copy a local version of amstex.tex to the document folder, miktex and texlive include amstex.

Comment: oh it's not in amstex.tex it's in your file (it would be better to put the log in your question not on google drive unless you promise to keep that link working forverer, as this question and answer will be kept)

Comment: Where should I put the files if I want to move them out of Google Drive? No I cannot guarantee they will be there forever. I was told to "\input amstex" (I didn't use to do that 35 years ago). If it is already included by MikTeX then it's no wonder that didn't help my case. So where do I find my missing fonts?

Answer (score 5):

Your log shows

```
(./FORMAT.TEX
! Font \bi=ambi10 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \font
```

so your local file `FORMAT.TEX` has a line

```
\font\bi=ambi10
```

you need to replace that by

```
\font\bi=cmbi10
```

and similarly replace any other reference to am fonts by cm equivalent which usually (always?) just means changing a to c.

The almost modern fonts were Knuth's prototype release of the computer modern fonts that have been the default fonts for TeX since the mid 1980s, the am fonts were essentially a test release and were not distributed after the computer modern design was finalised.

I presume you could in theory find them in a historic archive but you are for example using a later `amstex.tex` that has been updated to use cm, so updating FORMAT.TEX to match would be more consistent.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, that makes sense. Will the cm fonts look like the am fonts? Thanks David.

Comment: yes (well if you are a real typophile and stress about the exact shapes of some serifs or the thickness of some hairlines then no, but....)  what may matter more is that inter-letter kerns were adjusted/fixed more for cm so the widths of words can vary slightly which over a long paragraph can lead to different line breaking but anyway if the intention is to make a modern pdf suitable for this century you want to use the cm fonts as the am fonts were never available as scalable font formats (as they hadn't been invented:-)

Comment: ok great. So I changed all the references to am* to cm*. It found all fonts except one.kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmbi10

The command name is E:\w32TeX\texinstwin\bin\mktextfm

kpathsea: Running mktexmf cmbi10.mf

The command name is E:\w32TeX\texinstwin\bin\mktexmf
name = cmbi10, rootname = cmbi, pointsize = 10
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
Cannot find cmbi10.mf.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \bi=cmbi10 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again>
                   \font
l.14 \font
          \bsy=cmbsy10

Comment: bold (text) italic would be cmbxti10 @Pierre

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much David. I can now compile my 101-page document. The only remaining issue are the embedded figures (which were generated for the printer I had available then), and the tables of data I was reading on the fly. I should be able to work on my own on those two things. For now I either press Enter or specify a "null" input file. I will come back here if I have further questions since I know where the experts are.

One last question. Which executable do I use to convert the dvi file to PDF? Thanks again.

Comment: @Pierre you could (probably) use pdftex insted of tex then you would get a pdf instead of dvi, but otherwise use tex then dvips to get postscript then ps2pdf to get pdf. both dvips and ps2pdf are in miktex distribution

Comment: thanks again. It is so exhilarating to see my dissertation as a PDF. Feels like going back to the future (in 1985). I had not compiled this document in over 30 years. What a thrill. And of course the computing power of today's PCs makes the whole thing a snap to compile.

Comment: @Pierre mine is dated 1985 as well, but done on a golfball typewriter, you were so modern:-)

Comment: I had to be modern. Too many equations, so I couldn't afford to pay the department secretary to type it and risk countless errors, and then another retype, and on and on. Anyway I have more questions now on figures and images, but will start a new thread for that.